# Why it's important to use both EOF and '\0' together in this line of code?

Tags: c++, c, eof

Please excuse my poor English, I'm practicing C with "C Programming Language, 2nd ed" on chapter 4 section 4.1 there is a code for pattern search (UNIX program grep)

there is one line of code that i do not understand well

```
while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\0')
```

What confused me is `EOF` and `'\0'` aren't the same thing? using one of them isn't enough?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: EOF is not the same as '\0'

Comment: Are you sure it says `'\0'` and not `'\n'`? `'\0'` is not a character you would expect to be reading from stdin.

Comment: @hvd Actually you are right, i copped wrongly to Visual Studio, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: you should look for the EOF and any macro/definition before asking

Comment: Is it even possible to get `\0` from `getchar`? What key combination would that, even hypothetically, correspond to?

Comment: @Damon: standard input can come from anywhere, not always the keyboard.  If it's reading from a file, it's trivial to give it a `\0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EOF` is not the same as `'\0'`

`EOF` is End Of File

`'\0'` is a string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

- `'\0'` equals `0`
- `EOF` equals `-1`.

`-1 != 0` ---> `EOF != '\0'`